# Having Problem with displaying output stored in python List, How to display a list stored in database as a string in Python, flask

Tags: python, string, list, flask

I have made a program in which users can create channels and other Users can join it. Everything is fine but I have a column in my database "channel_members" in which I want to store all the names of the channel members. I have done it by storing it in a list, but when I try to output that list, I am facing some problems. I have applied a condition in my html template :

```
{% for member in members %} 
   <li>{{ member }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

so every member can be displayed. members in my condition is defined in below functions. I get weird output that is displayed in below image

[image]

This is how I get output

My models.py:

```
class Channel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "channel"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    channel_owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), 
    nullable=False)
    channel_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    channel_logo = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, 
    default='default.jpg')
    channel_description = db.Column(db.String(110), nullable=False, 
    default="Welcome to My 
    Channel")
    channel_members = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    channel_members_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

The program for creating the channel is defined in routes.py as :

```
channel_members_list = []
@app.route('/create_channel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_channel():
    form = CreateChannelForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        channel_members_count = 1
        channel = Channel(channel_name=form.channel_name.data,  
        channel_description = 
        form.channel_description.data , channel_logo =  
        save_picture(form.picture.data), 
        owner=current_user,
     `channel_members=channel_members_list,channel_members_count=channel_members_count)`
        channel_members_list.extend([current_user.username])
        channel.channel_members = channel_members_list
        db.session.add(channel)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

return render_template("create_channel.html", form=form)
```

The channel gets created and The name of current user is added in database in form of a list for example in database channel_members = {TalalIqbal}.
When I try to output the channel_members through a function:

```
@app.route("/channel_member_list/<channel_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def channel_member_list(channel_id):

    channel = Channel.query.get_or_404(channel_id)
    members = channel.channel_members

return render_template("channel_members_list.html", members=members)
```

The output I get is  also described in above pictures:

[image]

I want it (output)  to be displayed as one name in one line

I also tried the following in my create channel function in routes.py:

```
member = str(current_user.username)
channel_members_list.extend([member])
channel.channel_members = str(channel_members_list)
```

but it also did not work giving output as shown in below image:

[image]

How to get output that shows name of one channel member in one line?

Comment: It looks like the "members" variable that you're passing to "channel_members_list.html" template is a string, rather than a list of strings. But I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: May be, but what could be solution

Comment: May be because I am doing str(channel_members_list) What do you say jmaloney13?

Comment: @jmaloney13 I have tried doing only str(current_user.username) and removed str from channel_members_list, but no progress

Comment: What happens if you do members = [channel.channel_members] in the @app.route("/channel_member_list/<channel_id>" section?

Comment: @jmaloney13  Will give it a go and inform you shortly

Comment: @jmaloney13 This is the output I get by doing [channel.channel_members]                             
 :                                                                                                                                    ['We Chat! Official', 'TalalIqbal'] with channel_members = str(channel_members_list) and  {We Chat! Official} without str(channel_members_list)